# Use of Font Awesome into the html coding syntax

Tags: html

I want to put a font awesome icon such as  in html syntax as below. Please provide me with the right way to add it to html syntax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Javascript Form</title>            
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Testing</h1>
        <i class="fab fa-accessible-icon"></i>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Did you import fa ?

Comment: You need to import css, add this to head : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include the CDN or the files for font awesome in order to use it and work.

```html
<!-- fontawesome add me in the header -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />


<i class=" fa fa-handshake fa-5x "></i>
<i class=" fas fa-angry fa-5x "></i>
```

Comment: How to find the files for font awesome.

Comment: You can download them from their website. They put a link for that, I prefer to use CDN for that matter. As it is simpler and faster to setup.